# Add data with ImageField to a request in the view. Django and Rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to add an object to a request, this object have images and the "validated_data" reject this images and return a bad request.

Here the code:

***models.py***

```
def imagen_inmobiliaria(instance, file_name):
    return '{}/portada.jpg'.format(instance.nombre)


def logo_inmobiliaria(instance, file_name):
    return '{}/logo.jpg'.format(instance.nombre)


class Inmobiliaria(models.Model):
    portada = models.ImageField(upload_to=imagen_inmobiliaria, blank=True,
                                null=True)
    leyenda = models.TextField(max_length=1500, blank=True, null=True)
    logo = models.FileField(upload_to=logo_inmobiliaria, blank=True,
                            null=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    facebook = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    instagram = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    twitter = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    web = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    es_favorito = models.BooleanField()
    thumbnail = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='inmobiliarias',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

***views.py***

```
def create(self, request):
    usuario = request.user
    try:
# "inmobiliaria" is the object that have the ImageField
        inmobiliaria = Inmobiliaria.objects.get(user=usuario)
    except Exception as e:
        raise

    request.data['inmobiliaria'] = SimpleInmobiliariaSerializer(inmobiliaria, context={'request': request}).data
    print(request.data['inmobiliaria') # Look below to see this print
    return super().create(request)
```

**Print of request.data['inmobiliaria'] return this**:

```
inmobiliaria {'id': 17, 'telefono': '123', 'web': None, 'logo': 'http://localhost:8000/media/Prieba/logo.jpg', 'facebook': None, 'nombre': 'Prueba', 'twitter': None, 'leyenda': '', 'instagram': None, 'es_favorito': False, 'portada': 'http://localhost:8000/media/Prieba/portada_Q03uJtd.jpg', 'sucursales': [], 'thumbnail': 'http://localhost:8000/media/Prieba/portada.thumbnail'}
```

portada, logo and thumbnail are the images

***serializers.py***

```
class InmuebleSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ubicacion = UbicacionSerializer()
    inmobiliaria = SimpleInmobiliariaSerializer()
    caracteristicas = SimpleCaracteristicaSerializer(
    many=True, allow_null=True)
    instalaciones = SimpleInstalacionSerializer(many=True, allow_null=True)
    estado = SimpleEstadoSerializer()
    tipo_inmueble = SimpleTipoInmuebleSerializer()
    ambientes = SimpleAmbienteSerializer(many=True, allow_null=True)
    portfolios = SimplePortfolioSerializer(many=True, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Inmueble
        fields = ('id', 'nombre', 'descripcion', 'precio',
              'superficie_cubierta', 'superficie_descubierta',
              'inmobiliaria', 'caracteristicas', 'estado', 'instalaciones',
              'tipo_inmueble', 'ubicacion', 'es_favorito', 'qr_url',
              'portada', 'thumbnail', 'tipo_inmueble', 'ambientes',
              'portfolios')
        read_only_fields = ('es_favorito', 'qr_url', 'portada', 'thumbnail')

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Never print anything here, it crashed before this
        print('Inmobiliaria del serializer', validated_data.pop('inmobiliaria'))
```

**DRF return this in 'portada' and 'logo' fields:** 
*The information sent was not a file. Check the type of coding of the form.*

Comment: Actually, What are you trying to do here? What are you planning to do after mutating the request object?

Comment: When I do return super().create(request) it continues with the serializer's create method, in this method i save the object Inmueble (It not showing now for more simplicity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it just doing the same in the serializer:

```
@transaction.atomic
def create(self, validated_data):
usuario = self.context['request'].user
inmobiliaria = get_object_or_404(Inmobiliaria, user=usuario)
validated_data['inmobiliaria'] = inmobiliaria
```